# DAX measure calculation based on the different values in column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create measure which will calculate sum of sales orders.

I have a table:

| Sales Order ID | Sales Order Item | Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01 | 1 | 250 |
| 1 | 02 | 2 | 300 |
| 2 | 01 | 1 | 100 |
| 3 | 01 | 2 | 50 |

If one Sales Order has 1 and 2 type then should be calculated only type 2, when Sales Order has only one type then all value should be calculated. So in that case:

```
Sales Order 1 = 300 
Sales Order 2 = 100
Sales Order 3 = 50
```

Could you please help me how can I achieve this results?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you need:

```
SumConditional = 

var __typ2 = ADDCOLUMNS( SUMMARIZE('Sheet1 (2)', 'Sheet1 (2)'[Sales Order ID]), "MaxType", CALCULATE(MAX('Sheet1 (2)'[Type]) ))

return 
CALCULATE( SUM('Sheet1 (2)'[Amount]), TREATAS( __typ2,'Sheet1 (2)'[Sales Order ID],'Sheet1 (2)'[Type])  )
```

[image]